# Spark RDD with scala. Filtering with set.contains(x) throws org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to count the frequency of words of the 8th field of `dir/file.csv` without counting some words that are in the set `unwanted`.

Applying `.filter(word => !unwanted.contains(word))` throws `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`. How can I fix this issue ?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.rdd._

import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import scala.tools.nsc.io.File

object WordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("WordCount").getOrCreate()

    val unwanted =  Set("about", "also", "after", "been", "does", "that", "from", "gets", "goes", "have", "into", "there", "they", "them", "their", "then", "this", "what", "when", "where", "which", "while", "will", "with")

    val plots = loadData(spark)
    val words = plots.flatMap(r => r.toLowerCase.split("\\W+")).filter(word => word.length() > 3 && !unwanted.contains(word)).map(word => (word,1)).cache()
    val total = words.count()
    val counts = words.reduceByKey(_+_).mapValues(_/total).sortBy(_._2, ascending = false)
    val res = counts.take(100)
    for ((key, value) <- res){
      println("Word : " + key + " Freq : " + value)
    }
    spark.stop()
  }

  def loadData(spark: SparkSession) : RDD[String]= {
    val movieLensHomeDir = "/dir"
    val plots = spark.read.options(Map("header" -> "true", "delimiter" -> ","))
      .csv(movieLensHomeDir + "/file.csv").rdd
      .map(r => r.getString(7))
    plots
  }
}
```

Comment: unwanted cannot be retrieved by Spark executors, please try to use `val brdUnwanted = spark.sc().broadcast();` then use `.filter(word => !unwanted.getValue().contains(word))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could there be a typo ? I think that we should use the broadcasted variable inside the filter `val brdUnwanted = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(unwanted)` and `.filter(brdUnwanted.value.contains(word))`. I remember trying this and meeting the same error. I will try again just to be sure.

Comment: Now it throws a Null Pointer Exception. I don't know where I can put the variable.

Comment: I've tried your project locally (code on https://github.com/navispeed/stackoverflow-71401179), I didn't got any issue